# No sound in Ubuntu minimal + xbmc. Possible bug?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, xbmc

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 minimal+XBMC with no gnome interface.

```
lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)

aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC268 Analog [ALC268 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have tried speaker-test, alsamixer is at maximum of everything, AutoMute disabled, xbmc recognizes (on System -> Settings -> Audio Output) Audio Output Device : Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound s... (There are no other options).

I have tried also to turn off navigation sound (which i never heard) but someone posted it works. I've tried with oss4 instead of alsasound, doesn't work for me.

Does anybody have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Why are you mentioning alsa and oss, aren't you using puleseaudio? Do you have sound anywhere else in the system? Is pulseaudio installed? Please show us the output of `dpkg -l | grep ^ii.*pulse.*` and `pulseaudio`.

Comment: Or do you have sound in a live cd?

Comment: Use this script http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh and paste its output.

Comment: What do you get when you open a command prompt and type in `alsamixer`, check to see if the master volume, and any other channel you're using aren't muted